# Node Inspector not hitting breakpoint for Intern test

Tags: node.js, debugging, selenium, intern, node-inspector

I am trying to debug my intern test using node inspector. I followed all the steps correctly from [here](https://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/debug-nodejs-like-a-pro/). I gave it a run by performing the following command

1. Start Selenium[for intern test]
2. Run the intern test in node environment

   C:\node\node --debug-brk node_modules/intern/runner.js config=tests/intern
3. In another cmd I run the node inspector

   node-inspector --web-port=9999 &
4. Start the browser

   http://127.0.0.1:9999/?ws=127.0.0.1:9999&port=5858

I can see all the script of my project. I have break point set in one of the test component. But the moment I resume the debugger the test start running but the breakpoint is never hit. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add `debugger;` into your script as a break point